# How to capture Spring Security authentication token and save it in a database

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters

We are using a two-pronged approach to user authentication where we are using an in-memory authentication token store in clustered environment and saving the token in a shared database as well. Now I am able to get token using the in-memory store and authenticate users. Everything is working as expected.

I am looking for the following things :

1. Capture the token and save it in the database? How to achieve this with Spring Security (this should happen after successful authentication)?
2. If server restarts then I should still be able to validate the token from database.(if user name password is correct.)

   @Component
   public class CustomAuthSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

   ```
   @Override
   public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
           HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
           throws IOException, ServletException {
       System.out.println(request);
       System.out.println(response);

   }
   ```

   }

Following are my HTTP settings:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize"))
                .disable().headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/hello/")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/secure/**").authenticated();


    }
```

PS : It looks like adding an interceptor can help, however I am not sure how do I to get token from response. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any code is appreciated

Comment: Any comments , if more information is needed I can provide that .